# Sleuth doesn't show the trace id and the span id

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-sleuth

I am trying to run a Spring Boot application and trace its execution with the support of Sleuth.
The log shows the service name, but nothing for the trace id or the span id. All I get is [myservice,,,].

What am I missing?

Here are some lines from the log.

> 2017-04-30 14:41:38.750  INFO [myservice,,,] 7 --- [           main]
> s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing
> org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@5e57643e:
> startup date [Sun Apr 30 14:41:38 GMT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
>
> 2017-04-30 14:41:39.264  INFO [myservice,,,] 7 --- [           main]
> f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : JSR-330
> 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
>
> ...

Thanks

Comment: This is normal for startup. Sleuth is for distributed tracing. I.e. ingress and egress points from say an HTTP REST call or some MQ.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like Darren mentioned this is perfectly normal. What would you want to trace here? A trace is started by an rpc call or sth like that. Please read the docs where you can read about what distributed tracing is  and you  can watch my video where I explain how to use Sleuth

Comment: How is this normal? This link just returns "Hello World" and does some logging and he gets traceId and spanId. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-sleuth-single-application

Comment: Because in the link you have `logger.info("Hello Sleuth");` and @msayag has logged nothing

Comment: Ah, ok. But it doesn't start on RPC or I/O call. I use it within single service as well.